# React Native build apk app fail with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, gradlew, bundle-release-js-and-assets

So i just build a new react native app with typescript. And the problem here is when i run
`npm run build_apk`
it got error like below. And i think because i use typescript so my file name was index.tsx ,not index.js , but i don't know how to fix it.

This is how my build_apk command look like

`"build_apk": "cd android && .\\gradlew assembleRelease"`

[image]

Comment: in your tsconfig.json add `"allowJs": true, ` under `compilerOptions`. it will allow javascript files to be compiled

Comment: @RahmanHaroon i already add it but not working